# Synology DSM6 versus Slim Framework

Tags: slim, synology

I try for a while to make Slim Framework working on my Synology (DSM 6.1.3-15152 Update 1).

I already played with Slim in the past so I thought that will be easy... but nah... can't make the routing work. Always get a 404 except for the root.

I did make my .htaccess file correctly, but I can put anything in it the website just act as if the file was not there.

So it must be the AllowOverride All the problem...

and here I am : tons of .conf and other files that look like what I need but every time it don't work.

I'm not even sure to know if I have to restart something after editing / creating a someting.conf in some site-enabled folder.. so I restart everything. (webStation + apache server) and it take a looOong time to restart...

I try to make it work with WebStation + Apache Http Server 2.4 (as making it work with nginx look like even more complicated). The website is a virtualhost on port 7878...

I can access my Synology using ssh... so if someone know how to do it I will be glad. I loved Slim framework in a past project and I would like to use it again but man...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is dumb. I use a tool to sync my local files to my Synology. This tool always told me "everything sync successfully"... I just realized, this tool do not sync file that start with a "."

I was using Cloud Station Drive to sync my files and by default the option to sync file starting with a "." is disabled. I realized it by going straight in the folder using ssh.

I created manually my .htaccess file and now everything work.

I leave it here in case someone get the same stupid problem...

Comment: What is the name of this dumb tool? The fact that it does not sync dot files indicates this tool is probably not as dumb as you describe it. Dot files in many cases contain configurations for a specific environment, hence don't need to be synced. This​ tool probably has some options to sync dot files as well.

Comment: The real dumb in the story he's me I guess. I use the Cloud Station Drive, by Synology and by default the setting is to not sync "." files. But yes, it can be activated. I just did not realized that when I created the sync profile.

Comment: You just didn't notice the option, that's all :) It would be a good idea to edit your answer for those who face the similar issue.

Comment: Just did it. Thanks.